# Area shape calculating

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Can't find the area of the figure bounded by the curve in polar coordinates $$\phi=r\arctan(r), \phi=0, \phi=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 3}.$$ I tried use the formula $$S=\frac 12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 3}}(r^2(\phi))d\phi$$ but can't to find $r(\phi)$.

Comment: Please learn how to format maths on this site : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . This will help in attracting readers' attention

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get $r(\phi)$. Since 
$$d\phi=\left(\arctan r+\frac{r}{1+r^2}\right)dr$$
you can have
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 3}}\frac 12r^2d\phi&=\int_{0}^{\sqrt 3}\frac 12r^2\left(\arctan r+\frac{r}{1+r^2}\right)dr\\&=\frac 12\int_{0}^{\sqrt 3}r^2\arctan rdr+\frac 12\int_{0}^{\sqrt 3}\frac{r^3}{1+r^2}dr\end{align}$$

For the former, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106827/how-to-find-int-x2-arctanx-dx) will help.

Comment: Thanks. I understood your answer.